# Container is not set or can not be properly recognized. Use container() method to set it

Tags: reactjs, anychart, anychart-8.2

I'm following the example from here: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-meadow-476fso?file=/src/SunburstAnyChart.js:5181-6356

but in my setup I keep getting the error `Container is not set or can not be properly recognized. Use container() method to set it.` in the console. What could be the cause? AnyChart just keeps creating a div by itself with `<div id="ac-chart-container">` ignoring the reference id to the enclosing div that I am passing ... what could be wrong?

quoting it for convenience:

```
class SunburstAnyChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // makes tree from the data for the sample
    let dataTree = anychart.data.tree(data, "as-table");

    let chart = anychart.sunburst(dataTree);

    // set calculation mode
    chart.calculationMode("parent-independent");

    // set chart title
    chart.title("Europe Population");

    // set custom palette
    chart.palette(["#0288d1", "#d4e157", "#ff6e40", "#f8bbd0"]);

    // format chart labels
    chart.labels().format("{%Name}\n{%Value}{scale:(1000000)(1)|( mln)}");

    // format chart tooltip
    chart.tooltip().format("Population: {%Value}{scale:(1000000)(1)|( mln)}");

    // the fill specified in the data has priority
    // set point fill
    chart.fill(function () {
      return anychart.color.darken(this.parentColor, 0.15);
    });

    // set container id for the chart
    chart.container(props.containerId);

    // initiate chart drawing
    this.state = {
      chart: chart.draw()
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id={this.props.containerId}>
        <AnyChart instance={this.state.chart} title="" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SunburstAnyChart;
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find the solution? And the reason why you were getting that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The link to the forked codesandbox is here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-nash-zpxr8y

Basically, after reading the documentation, it is evident that there should be a `div` with `id=container`.

However,

```
    render() {
        return (
          <div id="container">
            <AnyChart instance={this.state.chart} title="" />
          </div>
        );
      }
```

did not work. So, what I realized after going through some samples is that, we need

```
 constructor() {
    super();
  
    let dataTree = anychart.data.tree(data, "as-table");
    let chart = anychart.sunburst(dataTree);

    // TODO: ADD THIS LINE
    let stage = anychart.graphics.create("container");

    chart.calculationMode("parent-independent");
    chart.title("Europe Population");
    chart.palette(["#0288d1", "#d4e157", "#ff6e40", "#f8bbd0"]);
    chart.labels().format("{%Name}\n{%Value}{scale:(1000000)(1)|( mln)}");
    chart.tooltip().format("Population: {%Value}{scale:(1000000)(1)|( mln)}");
    chart.fill(function () {
      return anychart.color.darken(this.parentColor, 0.15);
    });

    // TODO: ADD THIS LINE
    chart.container(stage);   

    // initiate chart drawing
    this.state = {
      chart: chart.draw()
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AnyChart instance={this.state.chart} title="title" />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The name inside can by any string

```
let stage = anychart.graphics.create("dog");
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-mountain-jvl4lf Use this instead as the code in above link has commented out.